# Wordpress: how to create a template that is still available when you switch theme?

Tags: wordpress, templates, themes

I have a custom template for my portfolio page. However, after switching theme, it's gone because it is in my previous theme's folder.

Technically, I can copy that file into my new theme folder. However, I plan to change theme every two weeks and this becomes non-trivial. Is there a way to always have a bunch of common template files available to me no matter when and how often I switch theme? (In other words, I want to create template files that are not dependent on themes.)

Thanks!

Comment: maybe there's a way to create a wp plugin that either copies template files when the theme is changed, or manipulate/include the plugin's folder as a template folder.

Answer (score 1):

There is, using template_redirect, which you would put in the functions.php file.

```
function uniquename_default_template() {

global $wpdb;

if(get_post_type() == 'posttype') : /* You could use is_single() instead of get_post_type() == '' or any type of conditional tag) */

include(TEMPLATEDIR . 'path/to/theme/file.php'); /* You could use TEMPLATEDIR to get a file from a template folder, or PLUGINDIR to get a file from the plugins directory - doesn't support HTTP requests */

exit; endif;

}

add_action('template_redirect', 'uniquename_default_template');
```

Hope it helps.